# Anyone know what this means? Getting the crash listed below on Android app with Facebook events logger

Tags: android, facebook, crash-reports

This is from the crash report at Google dev site for a published app using the Facebook appeventslogger.  Doesn't happen in testing.  Anyone know what this means?  It is happening across devices.  FB SDK 3.6.0.  The missing class is in that folder and in the build path.

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
 at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.flushAndWait(AppEventsLogger.java:760)
 at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.access$1(AppEventsLogger.java:732)
 at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger$2.run(AppEventsLogger.java:605)
 at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the v4 support library is getting exported with your APK? Sounds like it may not be. Are you using Eclipse? Is the support lib in your /libs directory?

Comment: Using Eclipse.  v4 is in the Android Private Libraries.  How would I know if it is being exported?

Comment: Go into your project properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export and make sure Android Private Libraries is listed and checked. If it is, that's probably not the problem. You could create a /libs directory in your project and drop the v4 library in there just to be sure; that will get it exported for sure. 

If you are still getting errors, it may be a version issue with the v4 support lib. I've had that problem more than a few times. Easily fixed by using a newer version of the library in your /libs dir.

Comment: Thanks.  Its in the build path.  I suspect there is a newer versionsomeplace, but I downloaded this last week from Facebook, but I don't think it is the latest version.  Just the one they linked to from the docs.

Comment: We gave up.  This was just too difficult to get to function with the ads APIs we were using.  We went with pay per click Facebook ads rather than pay per download, since we couldn't get the count for downloads to work without messing up other things.  Thanks for the reply.